# Malicious File type restriction in web appliction

Tags: javascript

How to restrict user from uploading .html, .exe files from file uploader. Even if I restrict a file upload by its extension, a user can still upload files by changing the file extension (e.g. 'filename.html' to 'filename.html.png'.

JS:

```
var allowedExtensions = ["png", "jpeg", "jpg"]; //mention the allowed extensions without '.'
var regex = new RegExp("[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{1,200}\.(" + allowedExtensions.join('|') + ")");
```

I'm using the above JavaScript code to allow only the file extensions mentioned above. But if the file name is changed to 'filename.html.png' how can I restrict such scenarios.

Note:- I can not restrict the filenames on basis of multiple dots present in it as a valid file name can contain 'filename V1.1.png'

Comment: For true security purposes, I don't believe there is anything you can do on the front end.  Because a malicious user with a modicum of technical know-how can circumvent any front end security measures you put in place, _true_ security checks for incoming data to your API happens in the back end.  While there are certainly some security considerations that are the purview of front end, most of what the front end will be doing for incoming data to the API will be convenience validation for the user, not true security against malicious actors.

Comment: You can try to determine the file type is one of the required types by reading the header/metadata of the file. There are few libraries to find the true file type. Extensions are just a shortcut for showing the file type and should not be relied upon.

Comment: @AlexanderNied I agree with you. Is there any way in the back end to restrict such cases?

Comment: @Panther could you please mention some of those libraries?

Comment: @SidharthaPrusty, if you can use node modules: https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-type would be one way to check

Comment: @EliasSchablowski I'm using ASP.NET MVC application which is not based on node modules. Do you have any solution for the same?

Comment: @SidharthaPrusty, I personally don't work with ASP.NET and can thus not recommend a solution, although [this](https://code-examples.net/en/q/13d83) may be useful (although you could also just check the first 2/8 bytes if they match `89 50 4E 47 0D 0A 1A 0A`(png( or `FF D8`(jpeg) and end with `FF D9`(jpeg only))

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't want to merely rely on a regex matching the file suffix; that is completely optional, and a malicious attacker could easily just rename their file to circumvent your security measures. Again, as Panther said, you'd want to look more into back-end security measures. However, as a way of answering your question regarding front-end security measures, you could read the [file signatures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures) of uploaded files (also known as "magic bytes") that specify what type of file it is. This will give you a better idea of what the file actually is, rather than purely relying on the file suffix.

Comment: Could you please suggest a way to handle the issue from back end as well? in case of an ASP.NET mvc application